# Backspace without adding to kill ring

Tags: kill-ring, deletion

Using Crtl+Backspace or Ctrl+Del adds the deleted text to the kill ring.
How can I prevent this from happening? I do not need to have every single piece of text sent to the kill ring when it gets deleted.

Side question: 
What's the purpose of this default setting anyway? :)

Comment: About the side question: probably to have a backup copy of what you delete without going through `undo`. Wild guess, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> `<C-delete>` runs the command kill-word (found in global-map), which is
>   an interactive compiled Lisp function in `‘simple.el’`.
>
> It is bound to `<C-delete>, M-d`.
>
> (kill-word ARG)
>
> Kill characters forward until encountering the end of a word. With
>   argument ARG, do this that many times.

Now, let's browse the source code:

```el
(defun kill-word (arg)                                                                                                     
  "Kill characters forward until encountering the end of a word.                                                           
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (kill-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point))))
```

Then, inside the documentation for the `kill-region` function we find:

> Kill ("cut") text between point and mark.
>   `This deletes the text from the buffer and saves it in the kill ring`.
>   The command [yank] can retrieve it from there. (If you want to save
>   the region without killing it, use [kill-ring-save].)
>
> [...]
>
> Lisp programs should use this function for killing text. (To delete
>   text, use `delete-region`.)

Now, if you want to go further, this is some function you can use, for deleting without copying to kill-ring:

```el
(defun my-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument, do this that many times.
This command does not push text to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region
   (point)
   (progn
     (forward-word arg)
     (point))))

(defun my-backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument, do this that many times.
This command does not push text to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive "p")
  (my-delete-word (- arg)))

(defun my-delete-line ()
  "Delete text from current position to end of line char.
This command does not push text to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive)
  (delete-region
   (point)
   (progn (end-of-line 1) (point)))
  (delete-char 1))

(defun my-delete-line-backward ()
  "Delete text between the beginning of the line to the cursor position.
This command does not push text to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive)
  (let (p1 p2)
    (setq p1 (point))
    (beginning-of-line 1)
    (setq p2 (point))
    (delete-region p1 p2)))

; bind them to emacs's default shortcut keys:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-k") 'my-delete-line-backward) ; Ctrl+Shift+k
(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'my-delete-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-d") 'my-delete-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-backspace>") 'my-backward-delete-word)
```

Courtesy of [ErgoEmacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_kill-ring.html)

Comment: thanks, that solved it. What about the side question? :p

Comment: @DanielHitzel Sorry, I don't have the answer to the side question :)

Comment: So I am not alone :D

Comment: Do I put these into init.el?

Answer (score 5):

Since Emacs 24, without any configuration, you can delete any text without adding it to the kill ring by selecting it and then pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. When the mark is active, these keys delete the region instead of just deleting the character before/after the cursor.

That is, move to one end of the text you want to delete, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, move to the other end, and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (or <kbd>Delete</kbd>) do delete the highlighted region. Or move to one end, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you use movement keys to go to the other end, and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Well, that's not the case for me with Emacs 25.1 in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to `advice` the functions you don't want affecting the kill-ring, in such a way that you'd save and restore the kill-ring when called interactively:

```el
(defun my/call-interactively-inhibit-kill-ring (fun &rest args)
  "Call FUN interactively saving the kill-ring when called interactively.
Otherwise call FUN with ARGS."
  (if (interactive-p)
      (let ((kill-ring '("dummy"))  ; Dummy value in case FUN tries to append.
            (kill-ring-yank-pointer nil))
        (call-interactively fun))
    (apply fun args)))

(defun my/inhibit-kill-ring-in (cmd)
  (advice-add cmd :around #'my/call-interactively-inhibit-kill-ring))

(my/inhibit-kill-ring-in 'backward-kill-word)
(my/inhibit-kill-ring-in 'kill-word)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it more easily this way:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>")
          '(lambda () (interactive) (backward-delete-char-untabify 1 nil)))
```

Calling `(backward-delete-char-untabify 1 nil)` tells Emacs to backward-delete one char (that's the `1` parameter) and that it refrains from copying to the ring (that's the `nil` parameter). You need a lambda (i.e. anonymous) function because you're binding a function with parameters to a key.

Comment: Backspace does not send things to the kill ring by default, I'm not sure how this answers the question.