# Yanking does not use top entry in the kill ring

Tags: yank, kill-ring, kill-text

I want to delete regions without adding them to the kill ring following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637351/emacs-how-to-delete-text-without-kill-ring):

```lisp
(defun backward-kill-word-no-kill-ring ()
  "Delete the previous word and remove it from the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (backward-kill-word 1)
  (setq kill-ring (cdr kill-ring))
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "M-DEL") 'backward-kill-word-no-kill-ring)
```

It fails and I don't understand why. If I type `abcd`, copy it with <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd>, and yank it with `C-y`, Emacs inserts `abcd` and the kill ring, viewed with `C-h v kill-ring RET`, is:

```
(Value:
(#("abcd" 0 4
    (fontified t))
...
```

If I type `123`, delete it with `M-DEL`, which calls my function, and then yank with `C-y`, Emacs inserts `https://www.fablabs.io/labs`, which I had copied 30 minutes ago and is no longer an entry in the kill ring, and the kill ring is:

```
Value:
(#("123" 0 3
   (fontified t))
  #("abcd" 0 4
    (fontified t))
...
```

Then I cut text with `C-w` (`kill-region`), yank in another buffer, and it's the same link that comes first and my cut text that comes second (after `M-y`).

Where does `yank` grab its text if not from the kill ring?

### Update

Following Tobias's comment, I had `save-interprogram-paste-before-kill` at `t`, and have the same behavior when I set it to `nil` and start Emacs with `emacs -Q`. When I follow the steps above, after `M-DEL` of `123`, Emacs inserts the last entry from the kill ring, `abcd`. (When I first asked the question, I may have missed that the inserted text was the last entry of the kill ring, even after searching for the string in the kill-ring information buffer.)

### Further udpate

[A similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22266/backspace-without-adding-to-kill-ring) asks how to delete text without adding to the kill ring. The solution there, as the answer by Tobias here, is more elegant than my first attempt. I edited the question to understand why Emacs is using the last entry in the kill ring instead of the top entry.

### Further update (10 March)

I follow the steps above with `emacs -Q`, copy `abcd` to the clipboard and yank it, copy the function and keybinding and execute it, and after `M-DEL` of `123`, Emacs inserts the last entry from the kill ring, `abcd`.

The kill ring after that insertion is:

```
Value:
("(defun backward-kill-word-no-kill-ring ()
  \"Delete the previous word and remove it from the kill ring.\"
  (interactive)
  (backward-kill-word 1)
  (setq kill-ring (cdr kill-ring))
  )

(global-set-key (kbd \"M-DEL\") 'backward-kill-word-no-kill-ring)"
 #("abcd" 0 4
   (fontified t)))
```

The Emacs version is:

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02
```

The values of `interprogram-paste-function` and `interprogram-cut-function` are the default ones, `gui-selection-value` and `gui-select-text`. The behavior is the same if I use `M-w` instead of `Cmd-C` to copy the first piece, `abcd`, to the kill ring.

Comment: What is the value of `save-interprogram-paste-before-kill`?

Comment: Side note: Emacs follows the namiong convention that `kill` means "delete plus put into the kill ring" where `delete` means "just delete without affecting the kill ring", so you can call your function `backward-delete-word`.

Comment: @Tobias: The value of `save-interprogram-paste-before-kill` is `t`, original value was `nil`. I set it with `(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)` before binding the key to the function.

Comment: If you are still interested in finding the cause of the strange kill-ring behavior, could you try with `save-interprogram-paste-before-kill` set to nil. Or better, could you try with `emacs -Q` and only your function definition?

Comment: @Tobias I checked with my function definition and binding from the question, and with either (1) `save-interprogram-paste-before-kill` set to `nil` and restarting Emacs, or (2) launching Emacs with `emacs -Q` and using the function and keybinding in the scratch buffer. The result is as I described in the question, except that it's the *last*  entry from the kill-ring that is pasted. In the course of that testing, I found weird behavior that I could not pin down and updated the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backspace without adding to kill ring](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22266/backspace-without-adding-to-kill-ring)

Comment: @Basil Yes, it answers part of the question. I don't know why Emacs uses the last entry in the kill ring instead of the top one.

Comment: @miguelmorin What do you mean it uses the last entry? I do not see how this follows from what you have stated above. Given that you use `Cmd-C` and that text that is not in the `kill-ring` unexpectedly appears when you `yank`, my suspicion is that all of this can be explained as some interaction between Emacs and the macOS clipboard(s). Check and/or change your values of `interprogram-paste-function` and `interprogram-cut-function`. Try using the Emacs binding `M-w` instead of `Cmd-C`.

Comment: @miguelmorin Please state your exact `M-x emacs-version RET` - is this vanilla GNU Emacs built for macOS, or some third-party build like Emacs.app, Aquamacs, etc.? I don't use macOS but judging from [`(emacs) Mac / GNUstep Basics`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mac-_002f-GNUstep-Basics.html) it sounds like you could be mixing your primary/secondary/clipboard selections - note that these are all different "copy/paste areas". See also [`(elisp) The Kill Ring`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Kill-Ring.html) and its subnodes.

Comment: @Basil I updated the question. Sorry for the confusion about "last entry", I now included the full kill ring. The behavior is the same with the default values of `interprogram-paste-function` and `interprogram-cut-function`, inherited from `emacs -Q`, and with `M-w` instead of `Cmd-C`. I believe `macOS` uses Quartz instead of X11, and thus am not sure that it uses GNUstep and the X-windows environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your `kill-ring` gets messed up. It might be that it is some inter-program action that modifies the `kill-ring`.

But the right way to implement [deleting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Deletion.html) instead of killing is:

```el
(defun delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point))))

(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-word (- arg)))
```

Note, that I [just copied the stuff from `simple.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/620f672518b1c009a028ebdb0fd1d4a0aabfa1d0/lisp/simple.el#L7306-L7316) and replaced `kill` with `delete`.